Conectar GCP con mi red (watchguard)
necesito conectar o vincular mi maquina virtual de GCP en donde tengo instalado ISSABEL PBX.
Si bien desde GCP configure una regla para que desde mi red se conecte a issabel.
El problema esta en que al llamar a otro anexo pierdo paquetes y la conexión se corta, puedo hacer ping desde mi red hasta la VM, pero desde GCP hasta Mi red no tengo ping.
En mi red tengo un firewall watchguard.
